# Searching a nvarchar(max) field

Tags: sql-server

Our application connects to a SQL Server database. There is a column that is `nvarchar(max)` that has been added an must be included in the search. The number of records in the this DB is only in the 10s of thousands and there are only a few hundred people using the application. I'm told to explore Full Text Search, is this necessary?

Comment: If you are going to search inside it a lot, then possibly. Look for all rows with BigLumpoftext Like '%X' or / and '%XY%' Or Not Like '%XYZ%' sort of thing, the more of that you do, the more valuable it will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is like asking, I work 5 miles away, and I was told to consider buying a car. Is this necessary? Too many variables to give you a simple and correct answer to your question. For example, is it a nice walk? Is there public transit available? Is your schedule flexible? Do you have to go far for lunch or run errands after work?

Full-Text Search can help if your typical searches are going to be `WHERE col LIKE '%foo%'` - but whether it is necessary depends on how large this column will get, whether your searches are true wildcard searches, your tolerance for millisecond vs. nanosecond queries, the amount of concurrency, even seemingly extraneous stuff like whether the data is always in memory and can be searched more efficiently.

The better answer is that you should try it. Populate a table with a copy of your data, add a full-text index, and see if your typical workload improves by using full-text queries instead of `LIKE`. It probably will, but there's no way for us to know for sure even if you add more specifics than ballpark row counts.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I ended up making a table structure that was more search friendly and indexable, then setting up a batch job to copy records from the live database to the reporting one.

In my case the original data didn't come close to needing an nvarchar(max) column so I could get away with that. Your mileage may vary. In any case, the answer is "try a few things and see what works for you".